# Laravel - can't catch PDO exceptions

Tags: laravel

I have this:

```
    $this->db = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And a try...catch block that appears to not do any catching:

```
    try {
        $this->SQL->execute($this->values);
        $this->insert_count++;
    } catch (PDOexception $e) {
        $this->errors[] = 'PDO error: ' . $e->getmessage();
        $this->error_count++;
    }
```

...because the script still exits on a PDO Exception:

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1062 Duplicate entry '14' for key 'laptops_asset_tag_unique'

So how do I catch / handle PDO errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you namespaced your Exception?

You have to import the PDOException to your class in order to use it.
Add the following statement at the top of your php file

```
use PDOException;
```

Comment: This is another error that will raise : CLASS NOT FOUND 'PDOException' ... (If exist)